# Can I search for two together in the Bloom filter?

Tags: ethereum

See that library for e.g:

https://github.com/joshstevens19/ethereum-bloom-filters

You can see that I can check if the Bloom filter contains a smart contract address and if it contains a log with a specific topic.

**Now my question:**

I would like to check if it contains a log to a specific smart contract. Is it possible? Think about using the Bloom filter to see if there is a specific SC that triggered a transfer.

Is it possible? If I will check both: Transfer event, and the smart contract, I will get many more false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ethereum bloom filter contains individual strings separately. It is basically a bag of strings, where only the format of the string distinguishes email addresses, ethereum addresses and topics. There is nothing tying related strings together, so you cannot use a bloom filter in the way you would like to.

Comment: The question is what the EVM exactly hashing and put in the Block header & Transaction receipt, and if it's allowed me to search for Event-triggered by a smart contract.
I'm now asking about the technical details what can be hashed. Instead, what the EVM is hashing.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I seem to have misunderstood something. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's answering. I will try to speak with Vitalik to have some cominated string in Eth2 :)